# Using @Sys.Any Entity For my Chat bot / Assistant Service(Design Issue)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to develop a chatbot / google assistant service for food ordering service, and I currently have it designed this way:

There is a dynamic menu list that will be fetched through an API every time the user asks for menu (new Order Intent)
Then menu categories name list will be displayed
Then the user sends the category name
The second follow up intent (selected category intent) catches it and fetches the food items in the category
Then user sends the food item name
Then next follow up intent (selected item intent) catches it and asks for quantity.

The problem here is since it is dynamic list I can not make use of custom entity and slot filling and train it, so i am currently using @sys.any entity. getting the category name from user and checking if it is present in the menu list from the webhook, if present display item list. if not present check spelling or enter correct menu category and reenter prompt. **then here since the "selected category intent" is already consumed so whatever i type now is taken as "item name" instead of "category"**

I am preventing this by matching output context from "selected category intent" fulfillment and input context in the "selected item intent". But there are problems with this approach such as once a category is selected I can not go back and change that, and it only works 5 times(lifespan of parent intent context) before going to fallback intent

I know this is really bad design but is there any way to make this better?

Any way to say if the user enters a wrong category name, no do not consume this intent yet go back and get the right category name?

Or if the user selects a category or item by mistake. any way yo go back to that previous intent and do that again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations that may help:

**Use Session Entities**

Since you are loading the categories and menu dynamically, you can also set Entities for these dynamically. To do this, you'll use Dialogflow's API to create [Session Entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/session-entities) that modify the Entity you have defined. Then you can train your Intent with phrases that use this Entity, but you'll dynamically modify the Entity when they start the conversation.

**Don't use Followup Intents**

Followup Intents are useful in very limited circumstances. Once you start chaining Followup Intents, it is usually a sign that you're trying to force the conversation to go in a particular way, and then you'll run into problems that you have when the conversation needs to take a slight turn.

Instead, go ahead and use top-level Intents for everything you're trying to do.

"But," I hear you asking, "How do I then make sure I handle the category selection before the menu selection?"

Well, to do that you can...

**Use Contexts**

You were on the right track when you said you were matching Output Context. You can not only *match* it, but go ahead and *control* which Contexts are set in your webhook. So you can use Input Contexts to narrow which Intent is matched at any state of your conversation, but only set the Output Context in your webhook fulfillment to determine which Contexts are valid at any stage of the conversation. You can clear Contexts that are no longer valid by setting their lifespan to 0.

So under this scheme:

- When you tell them the categories, set the "expectCategory" context.
- The "selected category" Intent is set to require the "expectCategory" Input Context.
- In the handler for this context

  - You'll tell them the menu
  - Set the "expectMenu" context
  - Clear the "expectCategory" context

**Most of all, remember...**

[Intents represent what the user *says*, and *not* how you react to what they say.](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1)